# Is "name" in Domain\name always the SamAccountName?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, ldap

I need to access data stored by the SamAccountName, but I'd like to avoid querying LDAP if possible. Can I can reliably get the SamAccountName by parsing `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` (assuming this is a Windows Authenticated asp.net application)?

For example, if the value is `MyCompany\myname` then I'd like to parse it to get the `myname` value after the slash and be confident this is the same value I would get back if I queried to get the SamAccountName.

Answer (score 1):

When using Windows Authentication, `HttpContext.User.Identity` is a `WindowsIdentity` object. In the [documentation for the `WindowsIdentity.Name` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.name?view=net-7.0#remarks), it says this under Remarks:

> The logon name is in the form DOMAIN\USERNAME

So yes, but it's a backslash (`\`), not a forward slash (`/`).

Comment: Thanks, I corrected my question. That doesn't quite answer my question though. Or perhaps it does, but maybe I just don't know enough about AD to be sure. That is, how do I know that "USERNAME" is always the same as the SamAccountName? From what I've learned since, I believe it is however it seems the username in the "Username@Domain" format can indeed be different than the SamAccountName. Additionally I read where someone says that is the format that was returned in Azure. I'll have to test it to be sure, but just leaving this comment here for anyone else with similar questions.

Comment: When it says that it's in the format `DOMAIN\USERNAME`, the "username" is always the `sAMAccountName`. The `userPrincipalName`, which is in the format `username@domain` will never be preceeded by `DOMAIN\`.